# Why is this jquery script creating multiple alerts when updating a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small script (I am a hobbyist) that allows updates to the text of a  by clicking on it and updating a popup. It works, but when I was testing it, I noticed that each time I click a , it seems to contain info from the last time, meaning that each time I click a td, the script takes longer to run (seen by the alert firing once the first time, twice the second click, and so on). I am assuming it has something to do with $(this). Yes, I know there is a table update plug in, but it is overkill for the three or 4 edits my user would make. Here is the code and a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alsosun/QuLQH/1/:

```
// clicking on a TD cell to update it
$('td').on('click', function () {

    $('#pop').popup('open');
    var cell = $(this).text();
    var org = $(this);
    $('#txt').val(cell);

    $('#close').on('click', function () {

        var TXT = $('#txt').val()
        alert(TXT)
        $(org).text(TXT)
        org = ""
    });

});
```

I had to add the org = "" to make it work --not sure why. should all the var be destroyed after the script runs?

Here is the html:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>this</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>thought</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="pop" data-role="popup">
    <input id='txt'></input> <a href='#' data-role='button' data-rel="back" id='close' </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move that binding for `#close` outside your `td` handler, else it's rebinding all the time when you click a `td`, hence the multiple cell updates! I also made `org` a global variable to be assigned the proper value of `this` whenever a `td` is clicked. Final code: http://jsfiddle.net/QuLQH/2/

```
var org;
$('td').on('click', function() {
    $('#pop').popup('open');
    var cell = $(this).text();
    org = $(this);
    $('#txt').val(cell)

});

$('#close').on('click', function(event) {
      var newTXT = $('#txt').val()
      //alert(newTXT) 
      $(org).html(newTXT)        
});
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I get it, now. I am just learning, and this issue clarifies the structure a lot!

Comment: A follow up question--if that is ok: When I use this on a page that has tables dynamically created, this script doesn't work on those. It does work on table td that are in the markup. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Cory -- Absolutely! The reason being is that your event handlers are registered at run time, so, since these dynamic items don't exist, the bindings don't work! Use `.on` (check the API for all the details) -- something like `$(document).on("click", "td", function() {` should do the trick.

Comment: It certainly did! Thanks a million. And, your description of the issue makes complete sense.